# npm build (nuxt build) does not create dist folder in amplify(aws codebuild) using nuxt spa mode

Tags: vue.js, single-page-application, nuxt.js, aws-amplify, aws-codebuild

I want to create dist folder, after running 'npm build'(nuxt build) in amplify.

I run npm build in my local(mac) , then dist folder is created.

I run 'ls -a' after 'npm build' , then dist folder does not exist in amplify.

```
                                 > nuxt build
2019-08-20T01:49:08.598Z [INFO]: # Executing command: ls -a
2019-08-20T01:49:08.602Z [INFO]: .
                                 ..
                                 amplify.sh
                                 amplify.yml
                                 assets
                                 components
                                 .editorconfig
                                 .eslintrc.js
                                 .git
                                 .gitignore
                                 layouts
                                 middleware
                                 node_modules
                                 .nuxt
                                 nuxt.config.js
                                 package.json
                                 package-lock.json
                                 pages
                                 plugins
                                 .prettierrc
                                 README.md
                                 static
                                 store
                                 .vscode
                                 yarn.lock
                                 # Completed phase: build
```

here is package.json

```
    {
        ...
        "scripts": {
        "dev": "nuxt",
        "build": "nuxt build",
        "start": "nuxt start",
        "generate": "nuxt generate",
        "lint": "eslint --ext .js,.vue --ignore-path .gitignore .",
        "precommit": "npm run lint"
      },
```

here is amplify.yml

```
version: 0.1
frontend:
  phases:
    preBuild:
      commands:
        - npm install
    build:
      commands:
        - npm run build 
        - ls -a
  artifacts:
    # IMPORTANT - Please verify your build output directory
    baseDirectory:
        dist
    files:
      - '**/*'
  cache:
    paths:
      - node_modules/**/*
```

I am waitng for your answer , thanks.

Comment: This is true. You have `.nuxt` instead. You will utilize that to build up your application.

Comment: @Ohgodwhy thanks for your reply . but in my understandings , .nuxt is for SSR. is this wrong ? and I try use .nuxt/dist/server/index.spa.html  , but it does not work well.

Comment: It doesn't work well because the path to all the `.js` and `.css` files is incorrect. You need to map them according to what the web server expects to deliver.

Comment: I tried 'npm run generate ', but it does not create dist folder..

Comment: @Ohgodwhy
I google 'nuxt codebuild ' and so on , but I can not find tutorial or answer to use .nuxt folder , I can only find a way to use 'dist' folder .
do you know some good tutorial or code to use .nuxt ?

Comment: @ISSEISUZUKI I have the same issue... Have you found a solution yet?

Comment: `nuxt generate` always creates `.nuxt` folder after which it will generate the `dist` folder. do you have mode set to `universal` in nuxt.config.js?

Comment: @timar I set spa in nuxt.config.js

Answer (score 5):

From the Nuxt documentation: https://nuxtjs.org/docs/2.x/directory-structure/dist

> The **dist** folder, short for distribution folder. It is dynamically generated when using the **nuxt generate** command and includes the generated production ready HTML files and assets that are necessary to deploy and run your statically generated Nuxt.js application.

Including **- npm run generate** into your amplify build commands will solve this issue

```
version: 1
frontend:
  phases:
    preBuild:
      commands:
        - npm install
    build:
      commands:
        - npm run generate
        - npm run build
  artifacts:
    baseDirectory: dist
  ...
```

Answer (score 1):

I solved it setting up the amplify.yml file. I changed `baseDirectory: dist` to `baseDirectory: .nuxt`.

Answer (score 1):

To build nuxt project using amplify, amplify does not generate dist directory on the fly. you have to generate it in your amplify YAML file with:
yarn generate or
npm run generate.
I solved this same issue using the yml snippet below.:

```
 version: 1
frontend:
  phases:
    preBuild:
      commands:
        - yarn install
    build:
      commands:
        - yarn generate
        - yarn run build
  artifacts:
    baseDirectory: dist
    files:
      - '**/*'
  cache:
    paths:
      - node_modules/**/*
```

Answer (score 0):

For Nuxt 3, the output directory is `.output`. Hence, your `baseDirectory` should be `.output/public` if your build command is `nuxt generate` because that's the directory that will contain the entry `index.html` file.

Combining the configuration from [Nitro's docs](https://nitro.unjs.io/deploy/providers/aws-amplify) and [Nuxt's deployment guide](https://nuxt.com/docs/getting-started/deployment), this is what worked for me:

```
version: 1
frontend:
  phases:
    preBuild:
      commands:
        - nvm use 18 && node --version
        - corepack enable && npx --yes nypm install
    build:
      commands:
        - pnpm generate
  artifacts:
    baseDirectory: .output/public
    files:
      - "**/*"
```