# Nuxt Generate doesn't create dist folder using CodeBuild

Tags: amazon-web-services, vue.js, single-page-application, nuxt.js, aws-codebuild

I trying to generate my Nuxt website using CodeBuild. Everything's seen to be good but after the command `npm run generate` there isn't any `dist` folder generated so I have nothing to upload in my S3 Bucket...

Do you know this issue? I have found [a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57565766/npm-build-nuxt-build-does-not-create-dist-folder-in-amplifyaws-codebuild-usi) but no one answered it.

Thanks in advance,

Comment: Can you run the 'npm run generate' command with any debugging option to see what it is doing.

Comment: Unfortunately, I didn't find the command to run `npm run generate` in debugging mode...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should install nuxt in your system with `npm i -g nuxt` and run `nuxt build`

Comment: Hello @filol ! do you have any explanation for this solution ? it's not really something I would recommend as the version you install globally might be different than the one you develop with :/
I'm having the same issue with the universal mode, no .nuxt generated :/

Comment: Hi @Gabriel i don't have one ... I just find this trick but i'm a beginner with nuxt :/